# ARM Template concat resources

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have in ARM template:

```
"parameters": {
    "applications": {
        "value": "app1|app2|...|app(n)"
    }
},
"variables": {
    "applications": "[split(parameters('applications'), '|')]"
},

{
    "name": "[concat('notificationhub', copyIndex())]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/',variables('notificationHubNamespace'))]"
     ],
    "copy": {
        "name": "notificationhubCopy",
        "count": "[length(variables('applications'))]"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "notificationHubNamespace": { "value" : "variables('notificationHubNamespace')]" },
        "notificationHubName": { "value": "[concat('notificationhub-', variables('applications')[copyIndex()])]" },
        ...        
        }
    }
},
```

How to concat created notificationhub1 and notificationhub2 into one value in app settings like

"notificationhub1.connection|notificationhub2.connection|...|notificationhub(n).connection"

or is there an option to dynamically create in app settings based on count properties with respective values?

```
{
    "name": "[variables('webappName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "resources": [
    {
        "name": "appsettings",
        "type": "config",
        "properties": {
            "MobileApps": "[parameters('applications')]",
            "NotificationHubs": "???",
              -- OR --
            "App1NotificationHub": "notificationhub1.connection"
            "App2NotificationHub": "notificationhub2.connection"
            "App(n)NotificationHub": "notificationhubn(n).connection"
        }

    }
},
```

Comment: what do you want to concat? resource id?

Comment: I want to concat [listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/authorizationRules', 'eventHubNamespaceName', 'keyName'),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString] foreach applications. Or I any other way include in application settings eventhub per application.

Comment: concat with what?

Comment: concat to have "notificationhub1resourceId|notificationhub2resourceId"

Comment: have you figured this out? i would think that this can be done but not straight forwardly... (using "collector" templates)

Answer (score 1):

I can't be 100% sure on this, but looking at what you have here something like this should work:

```
[concat(listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/authoriz‌​ationRules', 'eventHubNamespaceName', 'keyName'),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString, '|', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/authoriz‌​ationRules', 'eventHubNamespaceName', 'keyName'),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString)]
```

I can't verify if listkeys for eventhubs do work like this, but when you figure out how listkeys works, you should be able to paste that into the example above.
Also '|' might need escaping. I suppose escaping is done with `\`.

edit: Again, I'm not sure about this, I've never tried it, but you would want to use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#return-values-from-a-loop) and try to reproduce it with notification hubs instead of storage accounts.

Comment: That's fine with hard coded 2 application values, but this value will be passed to template. It could be one or ten. "applications": {
        "value": "app1|app2|..."
    }

Comment: ah, I got your idea. hold on, let me think about it.